# Apache Spark MultilayerPerceptronClassifier setting fatures

Tags: java, apache-spark, machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to do a multi class classification using org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassifier. Given below is the code I used. I have 262 features and I have to give the feature columns to the MultilayerPerceptronClassifier. Can someone explain me a way to give features to the MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.

I can use setFeaturesCol() method to give features but it is infeasible because by using it, I can add only one feature at a time but I have 262 features.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel;
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassifier;
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;

public class NN {

    final static String RESPONSE_VARIABLE = "Activity";
    public static void main(String args[]){
        // Load training data
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
        sparkConf.setAppName("test-client").setMaster("local[2]");
        sparkConf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");
        JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(javaSparkContext);

        // Convert data in csv format to Spark data frame
        DataFrame trainDataFrame = sqlContext.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                .option("inferSchema", "true")
                .option("header", "true")
                .load("/home/thamali/Desktop/Project/csv/libsvm/train.csv");

        DataFrame testDataFrame = sqlContext.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                .option("inferSchema", "true")
                .option("header", "true")
                .load("/home/thamali/Desktop/Project/csv/libsvm/train.csv");

        String [] predictors = trainDataFrame.columns();
        predictors =  ArrayUtils.removeElement(predictors, RESPONSE_VARIABLE);


// specify layers for the neural network:
// input layer of size 4 (features), two intermediate of size 5 and 4
// and output of size 3 (classes)
        int[] layers = new int[] {262, 50, 40, 12};
// create the trainer and set its parameters
        MultilayerPerceptronClassifier trainer = new MultilayerPerceptronClassifier()
                .setLayers(layers)
                .setBlockSize(128)
                .setSeed(1234L)
                .setMaxIter(100);
// train the model
        MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel model = trainer.fit(trainDataFrame);
// compute accuracy on the test set
        DataFrame  result = model.transform(testDataFrame);
        DataFrame predictionAndLabels = result.select("prediction", "label");
        MulticlassClassificationEvaluator evaluator = new MulticlassClassificationEvaluator()
                .setMetricName("accuracy");
        System.out.println("Accuracy = " + evaluator.evaluate(predictionAndLabels));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use Apache spark vector Assembler to create a vector containing all the necessary features.